# How to write python recursive generator and iterator

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I try to write myclass with suitable `__iter__` function. For example, below is my simplified binary tree class. Just like the method `printnode`, recursive functions are very common in programming. When I write `__iter__` of this class, I pick up a question that what should I do if I want to write a recursive `__iter__`. Each time the `__iter__` is called, it start from the very beginning of the function definition and of course it cannot use recursion like `printnode`. So I try to use generator. My question is: how to write recursive especially self-recursive generator or iterator.

p.s. There is non-recursive version of method of traversing binary tree, which is what I wrote below. But what should I do if recursion is inevitable or far simpler than non-recursion?

```
class BinaryTree:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None
        
    def insert(self, val):
        if self._root is None:
            self._root = BinaryTreeNode(val)
            return True
        ptr = self._root
        while True:
            if ptr._val == val:
                return False
            elif ptr._val < val:
                if ptr.rchild is None:
                    ptr.rchild = BinaryTreeNode(val)
                    return True
                ptr = ptr.rchild
            else:
                if ptr.lchild is None:
                    ptr.lchild = BinaryTreeNode(val)
                    return True
                ptr = ptr.lchild
                
    def __contains__(self, val):
        ptr = self._root
        while True:
            if ptr is None:
                return False
            if ptr._val == val:
                return True
            elif ptr._val < val:
                ptr = ptr.rchild
            else:
                ptr = ptr.lchild
                
    def printnode(self, root=None):
        if root is None:
            root = self._root
            print('tree node list:')
        if root.lchild is not None:
            self.printnode(root.lchild)
        print(root._val, end=', ')
        if root.rchild is not None:
            self.printnode(root.rchild)
        if root == self._root:
            print('')
            
    def __iter__(self):
        return BinaryTreeIterator(self)
    '''
    def pprint(self, ptr=''):
        if ptr == '':
            ptr = self._root
        if ptr is None:
            return
        print(f'{ptr._val}: '
              f'{ptr.lchild._val if ptr.lchild is not None else None} '
              f'{ptr.rchild._val if ptr.rchild is not None else None}')
        self.pprint(ptr.lchild)
        self.pprint(ptr.rchild)
    '''
    
class BinaryTreeNode:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
        self.lchild = None
        self.rchild = None

class BinaryTreeIterator:
    
    def __init__(self, BinaryTree):
        self.binarytree = BinaryTree
        self._iter = self.binarytree._root
        self._itergen = self.itergenerator(self._iter)
    
    def itergenerator(self, ptr):
        nodestack = []
        if ptr is None:
            return
        while True:
            while ptr.lchild is not None:
                nodestack.append(ptr)
                ptr = ptr.lchild
            yield ptr._val
            while ptr.rchild is None:
                if nodestack == []:
                    return
                ptr = nodestack.pop()
                yield ptr._val
            ptr = ptr.rchild
                
    def __next__(self):
        try:
            ret = next(self._itergen)
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopIteration
        return ret
```

Here is a simple test for binary tree and it worked correctly.

```
myset = BinaryTree()
for item in (2,1,3,5):
    myset.insert(item)

myset.printnode()
for item in myset:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a separate iterator class, implement the iterable's `__iter__` as a recursive generator, *on the node type*:

```
class BinaryTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
        self.lchild = None
        self.rchild = None
    def __iter__(self):
        if self.lchild is not None:
            yield from self.lchild
        yield self
        if self.rchild is not None:
            yield from self.rchild
```

Then the tree wrapper class can simply delegate to the root:

```
class BinaryTree:  
    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._root)
    # Etc.
```

A generator function really works like a function *that returns* a generator *object*, and such objects are iterators - they implement `__iter__` (to return themselves) and `__next__` (to yield the next item). Thus, we don't need a separate class to represent the iterator. By implementing the logic on the node, we can elegantly make the recursion work: each recursive call is to the `__iter__` method (indirectly via the `yield from` statement requesting iteration) *of another node instance*, and we can simply check for `None` as the base case.

Comment: If only it weren't inefficient...